# Can I add Teammate in GCP-connected SendGrid?

Tags: sendgrid

We are using SendGrid from Google Cloud Platform.

When I clicked on "Add Teammate" on the SendGrid admin screen, I got the following response:

```
> You can't add any more Teammates. Upgrade Plan.
```

Is it possible to add a Teammate in GCP-connected SendGrid?

The following article is in the SendGrid Official Knowledge Center.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/teammates/

```
> Free and Essentials customers can create 1 teammate per account.
```

We have contacted SendGrid support. The response was as follows.

> It appears that you would have to raise this issue directly with the
> folks from Google Support as your account has been made through them,
> we don't really have access to make such changes to your account.